# Excel VBA run macro automatically whenever a cell in a range is changed by drop down list

Tags: vba, excel

I do have a drop down list in every cell in `Tabelle3.Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow)`. If one of the options is selected in any row in this range `Then` the Values in `Cell A and B`of this row should be copied to the next free line in `Tablle10`

This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim lastrow As Long

  lastrow = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row

  If Target.Address = Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow) And Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow) <> "" Then
     Range("A9:B9").Copy
     Tabelle10.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     Application.CutCopyMode = False

  End If

End Sub
```

However, if I select any option in a cell in `Tabelle3.Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow)` `run-time error 13` occurs in this line

```
If Target.Address = Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow) And Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow) <> "" Then
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong here? :)

---

NOTE: First I run this code only for `Cell AV9`. Which worked perfectly fine. So I proberly have to adjust my above defined `Copy Range`as well

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$AV$9" And "$AV$9" <> "" Then
    Range("A9:BE9").Copy
    Tabelle10.Range("A9:BE9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Intersect as you cannot compare the address of a single cell with a range (not like for like for a start).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Tabelle3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AV9:AV" & lastrow)) Is Nothing And Target.Value <> "" Then
   Cells(Target.Row, "A").Resize(, 2).Copy
   Tabelle10.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SJR works smooth :) I just added `Set Rng = Tabelle10.UsedRange` `Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` to remove all duplicated rows. So `Tabelle10` is just listing everything once.